# How to transition a property on multiple elements simultaneously

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have been trying to transition the background color (and a few other) properties on multiple elements simultaneously.

To achieve this (since there are many types of target elements spread across the DOM), I have been trying to apply the transition with something like this.

```css
    .dark-mode-transition * {
      transition-property: background-color, border-color, color;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
```

The plan is to add the `dark-mode-transition` class to the top level just before the transition, and remove it after.

This approach works in Firefox (all the elements transition in sync as expected), but in Safari and Chrome some transitions appear to be waiting for others to finish before they trigger ([this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Barnyard/ot51db4x/8/) demonstrates the issue).

Has anyone run across an issue like this before? Is there a different approach I am missing? Any input would be appreciated!

---

I know all the target selectors could be listed like this

```css
    .dark-mode-transition .some-class,
    .dark-mode-transition .some-other-class,
    .dark-mode-transition .yet-another-class {

        transition-property: background-color, border-color, color;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;

    }
```

but I was hoping to avoid hardcoding every combination.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 main problem in your code.

1. The font size is decleared in relative unite (em)
2. Div1, Div2 and Div3 are child and grand child of one another.

So the issue is, each div's font size is changing depending on it's parent div.

Possible solution.
1. If you need parent child relationship between divs then change font-size unite to px.

2. If there is no problem separating the divs from each other and add one after one as sibling. then you can use relative unite for font size.

**Note** : don't use transition property all for huge number of items which's transition are triggered at the same time. It creates performance issue.

Also try to avoid * selector if you are adding transition on a huge number of element.
 Define specific property which you want to change. It also improve performance.

### Option one - separating divs

```css
.large .animate {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.animate {
  transition: font-size 0.5s;
}

body {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('text-container').classList.toggle('large')">Toggle</button>
<div id="text-container">
  <div id="one" class="animate">
    One

  </div>
  <div id="two" class="animate">
    Two
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="animate">
    Three
  </div>
  <div id="four">
    Four
  </div>
</div>
```

### Option two - changing the font size unite to px.

But there is a problem, in this approach. When it's returning to the initial state. Transition will trigger one after one. but same siblings will be trigger at the same time.

```css
.large .animate {
  font-size: 48px;
}
    
.animate {
  transition: font-size 0.5s;
 }

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
  
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('text-container').classList.toggle('large')">Toggle</button>
<div id="text-container">
  <div id="one" class="animate">
      One
      <div id="two" class="animate">
          Two
          <div id="three" class="animate">
              Three
              <div id="four" class="animate">
              Four
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```